# AllocConsole Questions

Tags: c++, windows

I read the MSDN documentation on `AllocConsole`, I do not understand one word referring to its purpose. In a very minor DLL tutorial he attaches a DLL to a simple console application and in the DLL, `AllocConsole` is called. When I remove it from the DLL code, nothing changes during runtime. So I'm curious as to its main purpose:

```
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
AllocConsole();
printf("\nInjected Successfully!");
msgBox(true);
break;
```

This has no difference during runtime as to when I remove AllocConsole.

Comment: What if the DLL is loaded into e.g. a GUI application without any existing console? If you check the return value of the function, you will probably see that it fails in the console application.

Comment: This code is WRONG WRONG WRONG. You should [*never* do any type of complex initialization inside `DllMain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx#general_best_practices). Calling printf and MsgBox are *giant* violations of this rule, and always wrong. AllocConsole is iffy; I'd err on the side of not doing it. Whatever tutorial you're reading this code in, stop reading it. The person who wrote it doesn't know what he's doing. (Besides, even if it were technically feasible to allocate a console in `DllMain`, it just doesn't make any sense for a DLL to do it.)

Comment: @CodyGray I created another header file which is included in the main cpp and a new cpp file i made. The header file defines a function which is then expanded in the new cpp file, and is called from when the Dll is attached. Is that the correct way to structure this?

Comment: A header file has nothing to do with this. This is not a problem with the *organization* of your code. You can organize it however you want, but as long as the code runs in the context of the AllocConsole function, you will have a problem. You absolutely must defer complex initiation so that it is done somewhere else. The common trick is for the DLL to export a function, called something clever like "InitializeLibrary", that the application (DLL's consumer) can call to initialize it *after* DllMain has already run. It is still unclear why a DLL needs a console window, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN documentation for [AllocConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> A process can be associated with only one console, so the AllocConsole
>   function fails if the calling process already has a console. A process
>   can use the FreeConsole function to detach itself from its current
>   console, then it can call AllocConsole to create a new console or
>   AttachConsole to attach to another console.

So, call it if the process doesn't have a console but you want it to have one. A common example of where you might do this is in a Windows (GUI) application, which does not automatically create and display a console. (Unlike a console application, which does, making AllocConsole rather useless.)

Comment: @CodyGray I now understand when you explained the GUI, I was just using a simple c# console program. But now when I attach to a GUI, with AllocConsole() in my code, I get a runtime error exception from the simple injector i have temporarily utilised. http://www.mediafire.com/download/tuxgoufx812181u/HV_INJECT.cs

Comment: @aaron I do not understand what you are trying to say. A GUI application does not have a console window unless you specifically call AllocConsole. Which you can do if you want, but you should *not* do it in DllMain. That was the point of my comment on the question. Calling AllocConsole does not "attach to a GUI", it attaches a console window to your application. If you only want a console window, then do not create a "Windows application", just make it a "console application". The console window will show up automatically, without your having to write any code.

Comment: If you have an additional question about the runtime exception that you're getting from that code, you should ask a new question about it. Be sure to include the code in the actual question. No one wants to have to use a shady download service just to see the code. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry, I'm just learning C++ and trying everything out, to attach a console windows to any Windows Form and print onto the console that it has been injected, I know I can do a messagebox, but I just want to try everything out and have a crack at it all :) I find it hard to understand C++ so I'm just trying to learn the language by doing stupid little things like this.